# dependency=[com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:apklib:7:compile] not found in workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maven-plugin

Sorry for adding just another "android maven google maps dependency not found" question, but I think that I have read most of the posts about it and applied all the proposed solutions with no success.

I have a maven Android project running OK with Google Maps V2 dependency that is not referenced using maven but via google-play-services_lib project imported in workspace and eclipse build path library dependency.

Now I am trying to configure the google-play-services dependency via pom, as I am implementing maven automated tests with Robolectric, but I am stuck with this error showing in first line of pom, with no quick-fix:

> dependency=[com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:apklib:7:compile] not found in workspace

What I have tried so far, after lots of googling, and checking results after each step without success:

- Initially installed google play services components to my local .m2 repository with android-maven-sdk-helper (following [these instructions](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer)), and add to project pom two dependencies to jar and apklib version 7, which is my locally installed version (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032154/how-to-add-google-maps-v2-sdk-to-maven-project-as-dependency)). After this it was supposed to work but the dependency error appeared.
- Remove from eclipse build path the reference to library google-play-services_lib (in project / preferences / Android / Libraries). Anyway, google-play-services_lib project is still in the workspace.
- Copy apklib from my local m2 repository into some place in workspace: I tried google-play-services_lib/bin, google-play-services_lib/libs, MyProject/libs. Tested using name google-play-services-7.apklib (as in repository file) and google-play-services.apklib.
- "Mavenise" the google-play-services_lib project included in the workspace, by running eclipse Configure / Convert to Maven project. I edited the generated pom to update packaging type to apklib: `<packaging>apklib</packaging>`, and added android-maven-plugin with `<extensions>true</extensions>` in order to recognize the apklib package type. I compiled the project with maven goal compile, with success, but I can not find the generated apklib file anywhere.

After each of these changes I do Maven / Update project, clean project, even restart Eclipse. No success: the dependency not found in space error is still there.

I don't know what else to try. Could it be something with the library name? The library project name is google.play-services_lib, with _lib suffix, and the jar referenced in eclipse android library build path is the _lib.jar, but the maven artifacts do not have the _lib suffix. I have also tried some renaming in the components and artifacts with no success, but I guess the problem could be there. Could someone post an example pom.xml for the mavenised google-play-services_lib project?

Another guess: when I mvn compile the mavenised library project, why can't I find the generated .apklib file, where is it? I checked the trace with mvn -X compile and didn't find any hint.

Environment and versions:

```
Eclipse Indigo
External maven 3.0.5 (embedded Maven 3.0.3 not used)
android-maven-plugin 3.6.0
maven-eclipse-plugin 2.8
m2e-android plugin (m2eclipse android integration) 0.4.2
Android API level 13
```

The pom.xml I added to google-play-services_lib project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>google-play-services_lib</groupId>
<artifactId>google-play-services_lib</artifactId>
<version>7</version>
<packaging>apklib</packaging>

<properties>
    <android-platform>13</android-platform>
    <android-emulator>13</android-emulator>
    <android-maven-plugin-version>3.6.0</android-maven-plugin-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <local-sdk-path>C:\NoProgramFiles\Android\android-sdk</local-sdk-path>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${android-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${local-sdk-path}</path>
                    <platform>${android-platform}</platform>
                </sdk>
                <emulator>
                    <avd>${android-emulator}</avd>
                </emulator>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: just get a lib like that

Comment: Last time I checked the m2e-android plugin it was not supporting the apklib depedencies, so this could explain your issue. Do they have implemented it recently?

Comment: @rciovati, this could be the point: there is a m2e-android
issue reported about this feature and I checked that the issue was closed, but I didn't notice the fixing version:  0.4.3 Beta 4. My current m2e-android plugin version is 0.4.2, so I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks! The issue report: [link](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/8)

Comment: @Satine sorry, this is not valid. This lib can't be added just putting the dependency in the pom, as it is an android library with its own resources.

Comment: @Diana let me know :) Or this could be the right time for switch to Android Studio (or IntelliJ) which support out of the box apklibs.

Comment: @rciovati Nope, I tested with m2e-android 0.4.3 (installed by adding to eclipse repository http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master and updating). Same error. I tested same different things than in the question post. So I guess the error is in my configuration.

Comment: @rciovati, I found the solution, please check my answer. The problem was not the m2e-android plugin, but some errors in my configuration and lib package generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was about artifacts naming and apklib not being generated in the apk library project. This is what was wrong:

- The groupId and artifactId in the library pom were wrong: they must fit the name specified in the error message (I should have read it more carefully).

The right values:

```
<groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
<artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
```

Instead of the ones generated by eclipse when converting the project to maven, which were based on the project name:

```
<groupId>google-play-services_lib</groupId>
<artifactId>google-play-services_lib</artifactId>
```

- The apklib is not generated with `mvn compile`, the right instruction for that is `mvn package`. This way the apklib file gets generated in target folder of the project library.

So m2e-android 0.4.2 supports apklib dependency with mavenised google-play-services apklib, although the library project still has to be included in the workspace.

Final note: I got run time errors when running the maps activities in the real device:

```
07-08 09:42:45.170: W/dalvikvm(27953): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4296: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap;.setMapType (I)V
07-08 09:42:45.180: E/dalvikvm(27953): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method mypackage.MyMapActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded
07-08 09:42:45.180: W/dalvikvm(27953): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 801 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lmyapp/MyMapActivity;
07-08 09:42:45.180: E/dalvikvm(27953): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method mypackage.MyMapActivity.onCreate
07-08 09:42:45.200: E/AndroidRuntime(27953): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MyMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
```

It seems that the maps library was not included in the app apk. My fix: in `google-play_services_lib` project eclipse Properties / Java Build Path / Order and Export tab I checked the Android Private Libraries checkbox, so the original google maps jar is installed in the running device.

Answer (score 1):

If problem persist with naming mismatch resolved (same name in library pom and project pom), after updating maven project (project explorer, right click any project->maven->update maven project)
**try just deleting that message (!!)**.

I problem tab, right-click error message and select 'Delete'. Worked for me and for [Kevin Peck- Eclipse dependency not found in workspace fix](http://kevsaidwhat.blogspot.com/2013/02/eclipse-dependency-not-found-in.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that errors could get 'stuck' in eclipse. Good to know they can be removed this way.